# How to render a different action without reload the whole page when I submit a Symfony form with Turbo?

Tags: forms, symfony, turbolinks

On my user profile page, I have a turbo frame with src attribute for render an avatar upload form.

```twig
<turbo-frame id="avatar_form_frame" src="{{ path('avatar_edit') }}">
    Loading avatar form...
</turbo-frame>
```

When submited, the avatar file is saved and the form is rendered again:

[image]

```
<?php

    #[Route('/avatar', name: 'avatar_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function avatar_edit(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader, ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(AvatarFormType::class, $user, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('avatar_edit'),
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var UploadedFile $avatarFile */
            $avatarFile = $form->get('avatar')->getData();
            if ($avatarFile) {
                $avatarFileName = $fileUploader->upload($avatarFile);
                $user->setAvatarFilename($avatarFileName);
            }

            $em = $doctrine->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->renderForm('user/avatar_edit.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

That code work, but my problem is that when the form is submitting, the whole page is reloaded instead of the frame being updated.

The avatar form is inside an turbo frame: `<turbo-frame id="avatar_form_frame">`

I don't have that problem when I submit a form inside a frame who respond with the same controller action.

Comment: I have find the problem, I submit the form using a stimulus controller `submitForm(e) { e.currentTarget.form.submit() }` when the input field is changed. Turbo don't catch the form submit here. I search a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.form.requestSubmit()` insted `this.form.submit()` for form submit, turbo don't catch submit with the `submit()` method.